# Which Christian groups believe that Christianity is not for all humans?

Tags: conversion, non-christians

In some religions, it is permissible for non-members to continue being non-members. An example would be Judaism, where non-Jews only have to follow Seven Laws of Noah. In other words, for Jews, it is okay for non-Jews to not practice Judaism as Jews do.

In contrast, Muslims believe that the entirety of their religion is universal and should be followed by all humans. I am currently learning about Christianity. From what I have read, Christians also believe that every human being should be Christian. What are the major Christian viewpoints?

Comment: This question is a tad too open because there are several Christian viewpoints to tackle and they don't agree with each other necessarily.   (I think the same can be said of Islam and Judaism FWIW)

Comment: @PeterTurner We should really have an overview question on universalism though, and I couldn't find one that already exists.

Comment: @curiousdannii good point. Flux, if you're really asking if there are any groups within Christianity that don't require full membership.  That's an easy edit to make this question on topic.

Comment: @PeterTurner I have edited my question. I hope it is on-topic. Also, can you help me select the correct tags? I think the tags may be incorrect as I am new to this.

Comment: It would be interesting to tabulate the position of general Christianity regarding _God now commandeth all men everywhere to repent_ ... and...  _ye must be born again_  ...and ... _he that cometh to me, I will in no wise cast out_. There is a difference between an _obligation upon all_ (under threat of the sword) and an _invitation to all_ with the reward of eternal Life. Upvoted +1 in the hope of a successful edit.

Comment: One of the main reasons Christianity eventually abandoned the necessity of keeping the Mosaic Law for its converts was precisely so that its message might be(come) universal.

Comment: I think all you need in order for me to vote to reopen the question is to explicitly ask something like "what is an overview of the major Christian viewpoints?"

Comment: Not to belabor it to much, but could you edit in Matt Gutting's comment as well.  This specifically makes it so people who attempt to answer you're question don't just post their opinion on the matter.

Comment: @PeterTurner Edited.

Comment: I think some types of Calvinism could be understood to say 'the gospel' itself and the work of Christ are not meant for all humanity, and some dispensationalists in the early years (1800s) could be implied to mean that practicing Jews were going to be judged under a different standard.